# Pipe to my program as a log rotator

Tags: c++, linux, terminal, pipe, stdin

I'm trying to implement my own log rotator (create new log file whenever filesize reaches 10 MB). The part that reads the standard input and writes it to the file is this:

```
fstream file("log.txt", ios::out | ios::app);
while (std::cin >> lineInput) {
    file << lineInput;
}
```

But the problem is that piped data gets ruined. Tabs and new lines are always lost. So for example if my program's name is `LogRotator`, then the command:

```
ls | ./LogRotator
```

Just concatenates all the file names together, like this:

```
LogRotatormain.oMakefile
```

while the output of `ls` is:

```
LogRotator main.o Makefile
```

**My question:** How can I make the standard streaming preserve everything, including tabs, newlines, etc.?

Comment: You might omit formatted input/output and use read/write (and similar)  instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Dieter Lücking's hint, I found the way to do it. So one has to use an unformatted read. The following works fine:

```
fstream file("log.txt", ios::out | ios::app);
while (getline(cin,lineInput,'\n'))
{
    file << lineInput;
}
```

Comment: What exactly makes that "unformatted"? It's so formatted it's completely non-portable, which is amazing considering you're using pure STL.

Comment: @Blindy The function doesn't do any string processing and doesn't judge the input by its contents (except when the delimiter is met, but the delimiter is also delivered with the text). It delivers it as it was read. Other treatments like streaming to `std::cin` will modify the input some times. For example it would change a `\n` to a new line. This is how I understand it.

Comment: It most certainly does not, stream block copying is done with `ifstream::read` and `ofstream::write`. Both `getline` and `operator<<` change your data, and this is thoroughly documented on an OS by OS basis.

Comment: @Blindy I'm not an expert in this topic specifically, and still learning. But this code works and doesn't look as modifying the data at all. My logs are fine! How can this be explained?

Comment: @Blindly: of course `getline` if a formatted io function and should only be used for text, not binary. But it reads the text line by line an do not modify the text in the line... except for eventual charset convertions. So it is exactly what The Quantum Physicist wants. He does not want to change log file in the middle of a line, what should be explicitely dealt for with raw io functions

Comment: @SergeBallesta I think I misunderstood what "formatted" means. So apparently it means "not binary". Thanks for the information and the clarification!