# C++: Linux: Pipe to my program from multiple threads or streams other than `cout`

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, pipe, stdin

Following up from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31894218/c-linux-pipe-to-my-program-as-a-log-rotator), I noticed that two types of output are not caught by my `LogRotator` program, when such a piping is called:

```
$ ./MyMainProgram | ./LogRotator
```

The cases when my `LogRotator` `C++` program doesn't catch the output information is:

1- When from `MyMainProgram`, I use streams other than `std::cout`. For example, `std::clog`.

2- When `MyMainProgram` uses multiple threads. In `MyMainProgram` I use `boost::thread_group`, and everything I `std::cout` in the new threads isn't caught by `LogRotator`.

This behavior is normal in linux when such a call is made:

```
./MyMainProgram > log.txt
```

But then this can be solved using the call

```
./MyMainProgram > log.txt 2> stderr_log.txt
```

How can I solve this problem the same way with piping, such that my LogRotator catches everything?

Comment: How can `LogRotator` catch stdout and stderr in separate streams? There is only one input stream, stdin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will combine STDERR into STDOUT before piping to LogRotator:

```
./MyMainProgram 2>&1 | ./LogRotator
```